# how to get a list of dependencies in .net core 3.1?

Tags: api, rest, .net-core, runtime, .net-core-3.1

Here is the problem:

I need to get a list of dependencies and its version if available. I'm using .net core 3.1.

First of all, I thought that I need two things:
1.- a list of assemblies that are referenced in the current assembly at runtime. In order to do that I can use Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies in Reflection. I am guessing that this will include a list of nuget packages, and the version is easy to get, and of course the .net core package and version.

2.- a list of rest api calls, in this case I don't need the version number as it is not available. In this case I don't have a clue. Is there any way that I can get a dynamic list of rest api calls at runtime? So far, I haven't found anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is not a class that gets this information. In most of the cases, the api call details are stored somewhere, usually appsettings.json, so retrieve them from here.